# Append a multiple line variable to a new line after last pattern match occurrence

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, awk, sed

I would like to achieve this with preferably **sed**, but open to any other **bash** programming language:

I have a variable `$bonding` with the following lines/strings included:

```
add bonding group 0 
add bonding group 1 
add bonding group 2
```

I also have a text file that includes a random amount of identical string(s)/line(s) text:

```
Some identical text
Some identical text
Some identical text
Some different text
```

I want to append the variable `$bonding` to a new line at the end of the last pattern match in the file:

```
Desired Output:

Some identical text
Some identical text
Some identical text
add bonding group 0 
add bonding group 1 
add bonding group 2 
Some different text
```

Remember the amount of identical strings/lines in the text file can be random.

I have tried creating an `array variable` and using `sed` to get the desired output:

```
declare -a bonding
IFS=$'\n'
bonding=`grep -E 'bonding' bonding.txt`

sed "/some identical text/a\\"${bonding[@]}"" file
```

But this takes the first string in the array and appends to a new line after each `some identical text` string:

```
Wrong Output:

Some identical text
add bonding group 0 
Some identical text
add bonding group 0 
Some identical text
add bonding group 0
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated to get the desired output...

Comment: Any time you have a problem involving multiple lines, sed is the wrong tool. sed is for simple substitutions on a single line and for anything else you need to use awk.

Comment: I figured the case.  I'm not extremely proficient with awk, so following your answer is a bit foreign... An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, I've added an explanation. Otherwise, this is very basic awk stuff so `man awk` and I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
var="$var" perl -0pe 's/.*\nSome identical text/$&\n$ENV{"var"}/s' file
```

(as you expected, `$var` is the whole variable with expected lines to append)

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the file twice, the first time (NR==FNR) to identify the line number of the last line that contains your target string, and the second time to print all lines and then additionally print the "bonding" lines when the current line number is the same as the one you identified on your first pass:

```
$ awk -v tgt="Some identical text" -v bonding="$bonding" '
    NR==FNR { if ($0==tgt) nr=NR; next }
    { print }
    FNR==nr { print bonding }
' file file
Some identical text
Some identical text
Some identical text
add bonding group 0
add bonding group 1
add bonding group 2
Some different text
```

or with GNU awk for multi-char RS if your target string contains no RE metacharacters you can read the whole file at one time and then just do a substitution to replace the block of repeated target lines with that same block followed by your bonding string:

```
$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= -v tgt="Some identical text" -v bonding="$bonding" '
    { sub("("tgt"\n)+","&"bonding"\n") } 1
' file
Some identical text
Some identical text
Some identical text
add bonding group 0
add bonding group 1
add bonding group 2
Some different text
```

Comment: When using the `gawk` command, as it seems quicker, I'm getting the `$bonding` strings outputted only after the first occurrence of `Some identical text`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Your input file must not be the same as you posted. Maybe you have whitespace at the end of some lines? If you want to ignore trailing spaces you could change `\n` to `[[:blank:]]*\n` in the first sub() arg. If it's not that you'd need to edit your question to show your real input file for us to be able to help you.